# Get function return value inside promise on spyOn service - Jasmine Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm testing a function that receives a value from a promise, and concat this value (string) to an url. The implementation of the function it's ok.

```
  var resp = {"payment": {
    "additional_information": {
      "skuSeatIds": "[{\"sku\":\"5234\",\"Description\":\"Advanced\",\"seatId\":792}]"
    }}};


   var promise = Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(resp.payment.additional_information.skuSeatIds));
   var update = spyOn(doneService, 'getOrderInfo').and.returnValue(promise);


   var url = controller.setSeatIdLink();
   expect(url).toBe('http://localhost:4000/#!/search?type=Selector&seatId=792');
});
```

Then i have the function that call doneService.getOrderInfo()

```
  function setSeatIdLink () {
    doneService.getOrderInfo(store.get('orderId')).then(function(resp){
           var stri = vm.modalSelectorUrl.concat(resp[0].seatId);
            vm.modalSelectorUrl = stri;
            return vm.modalSelectorUrl;
    });
  }
```

vm.modalSelectorUrl is set with the url correctly. The spyOn returns the value fine. If i log "vm.modalSelectorUrl", the url it's ok. But i get undefined on the expect(url)...

If i hardcode the return  outside the scope of .then(function(){ ... , the return works.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here your function `setSeatIdLink`is not returning anything.
Return statement is inside `then` function and not in `setSeatIdLink` function.
And that's the reason it is returning `undefined` which gets stored in `url`.

Try asserting `vm.modalSelectorUrl` instead.

```
function setSeatIdLink () {
    doneService.getOrderInfo(store.get('orderId')).then(function(resp){
           var stri = vm.modalSelectorUrl.concat(resp[0].seatId);
            vm.modalSelectorUrl = stri;
            return vm.modalSelectorUrl;
    });
  }
```

**UPDATES**

Change your function like this

```
function setSeatIdLink() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    doneService.getOrderInfo(store.get('orderId')).then(function (resp) {
        var stri = vm.modalSelectorUrl.concat(resp[0].seatId);
        vm.modalSelectorUrl = stri;
        defer.resolve(vm.modalSelectorUrl);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

And test case like this

```
it('testcase', function (done) {
    //your code
    var url = controller.setSeatIdLink().then(function (url) {
        expect(url).toBe('http://localhost:4000/#!/search?type=Selector&seatId=792');
        done();
    });
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If i assert vm.modalSelectorUrl i get the original value without the concatenation. @ashish

Comment: I edit the code as above, now i'm getting this error:  Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Comment: Try to add `scope.$apply()` after `controller.setSeatIdLink()` call in test case.

Comment: same thing. I wonder if there is a way to check if variables are set as expected inside the function. Because it would be very helpful, if given a response, the logic set the variables as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a function that returns the promise. If you're using AngularJS best to stick with $q, although I'm sure it would work fine either way.

```
var mock_func = function(data) {
   return $q.resolve(data);
};

spyOn(func, 'method').and.callFake(mock_func({
   data: 'to_return'
}));
```